# Are "hTTp/1.0" and "htTP/1.1" case-sensitive?

Tags: parsing, http, specifications, rfc, standards-compliance

In 2002, Roy Fielding states that [HTTP version should be case-sensitive in an RFC errata](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2002JulSep/0066.html):

> Personally, I never had any intention that the "HTTP" be
>   case-insensitive, and I am not aware of any clients that send it
>   lowercase, nor any server that would accept it as lowercase.  Doing so
>   is a waste of cycles.  **So, I'd like that paragraph above to say:**
>
> > The version of an HTTP message is indicated by an HTTP-Version field
> >     in the first line of the message.  **HTTP-Version is case-sensitive**.

However, [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.1) doesn't seem to be updated with his proposal.

So, are HTTP versions case-sensitive?

In other words, can a HTTP client/server send the HTTP version as `hTtP/1.1` and still claim to be RFC-compliant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on to Julian's answer two years ago, RFC 7230 (which replaces 2616) now explicitly states that [HTTP-Version is case-sensitive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-80):

> A.2.  Changes from RFC 2616
>
> .........
>
> The HTTP-version ABNF production has been **clarified to be case-sensitive**.  Additionally, version numbers have been restricted to single digits, due to the fact that implementations are known to handle multi-digit version numbers incorrectly.  (Section 2.6)

And [Section 2.6. Protocol Versioning](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.6):

> The version of an HTTP message is indicated by an HTTP-version field
> in the first line of the message.  HTTP-version is case-sensitive.
>
> `HTTP-version  = HTTP-name "/"` [`DIGIT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#page-8) `"." DIGIT`
>      `HTTP-name     = %x48.54.54.50 ; "HTTP", case-sensitive`

Answer (score 3):

The answer is here: http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/1. And yes, RFC 2616 is being updated.